# laravel search query using whereHas returns undefined via ajax call

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have this issue where when searching the database using ajax I am getting an undefined message in the console not sure where this is going wrong as it works in testing. what I want to achieve is to get results matching the search query, below is what I am currently using.

while I was testing this, it works...it returns a collection of 2 arrays of objects...

[image]

```
public function getBusinesses(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $businesses = Business::whereHas('address' , function($query) {
            $query->where('area', 'LIKE','%'.request('location').'%');
        })->whereHas('service', function($query) {
            $query->where('service', request('keyword'));
        })->whereHas('service.keywords', function($query){
            $query->where('keyword', request('keyword'));
        })->with(['ratings' => function($query){
        }])->with(['address' => function($query){}])->select('id','name','business_description')->get();
        return response()->json($businesses);
    }
}
```

This is the javascript when the call is successful

```
      response.forEach(function(data){
        $('#main-content').append(`<div class="section-title-dark"><p>Businesses in your area </p> </div><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-3 item-mb"><div class="service-box1 bg-body text-center"><img src="img/service/service8.png" alt="service" class="img-fluid"><div  style="font-weight:300; font-size:85%; padding:10px; flex:1">${data.ratings[0].comment}</div></div></div><div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-9 item-mb"><div class="service-box1 bg-body text-center"><p class="img-fluid business-name"><a href="/business/${data.name}/${data.id}"> ${data.name} </a></p><div class="rating-score pull-right" style="display: inline-block;background-color: #1ec4b4;color: #ffffff;padding: 5px;width: 35px; text-align: center;">4.9</div><div class="clearfix total-reviews text-small pull-right" style="padding-top:1%; padding-left:90%">26 reviews</div><p class="business-description mb-none" style="font-weight:300;font-size:85%;">${data.business_description}</p><div style="padding-left:82%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default-outline btn-sm block" style="    background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #cccccc; color: #000000;">Request a Quote</a></div></div></div>`
        );
        console.log(data.id);
      });
```

This following laravel code seems to work but it returns businesses which do not have the address requested in the search query and this is not what I want.

```
if($request->ajax()){
    $businesses = Business::whereHas('address' , function($query) {
        $query->where('area', 'LIKE','%'.request('location').'%');
    })->whereHas('service', function($query) {
        $query->where('service', 'LIKE','%'.request('keyword').'%');
    })->whereHas('service.keywords', function($query){
        $query->where('keyword', 'LIKE','%'.request('keyword').'%');
    })->with(['ratings' => function($query){
    }])->with(['address' => function($query){}])->select('id','name','business_description')->get();
    return response()->json($businesses);
}
```

Comment: Getting an `Undefined` error in your console would lead me to believe that you have an issue in your JS. Are you using a variable called `message` in your JS that hasn't been defined?

Comment: No, I don't have a variable called message bro in JS.

Comment: what is the output from the console log `data` only.. ?

Comment: It is an empty array

Comment: Please see the last piece of code edited above